hex representation of char string in PL/1
In PL/1 , 'C1C2C3'X is the hexadecimal representation of the character string 'ABC'.
Is this correct? If yes, how is this arrived at?

On certain IBM or compatible machines it is because they use EBCDIC. This is a property of the platform, not the language; PL/I also works on machines using other character codes like ASCII, but few people use it so.

In hex, usually 'A' is 10, 'B' is 11, 'C' is 12. In this case are the hex values 'C1', 'C2' & 'C3' for 'A', 'B', 'C' respectively?

Yes hex C1 is 'A' in EBCDIC, C2 is 'B', etc, as shown in the reference I linked

So, you are looking at the table in the link you shared? So, in EBCDIC 'a' has value '81', 'b' is '82', '1' is 'F1', 2 is 'F2' and so on. Is this correct?

Ayup.<!-- padding>
